# Should I use popups inside a wizard form?

Tags: popup, wizard, long-forms

I have a very long wizard form and I need to add even more information within each step. For now I have decided to add it using pop-ups. I know it is a bad practice, but I can not come up with a better idea. Can anyone help!
[image]

In order to add a new Linked site you will have the following popup:
[image]

Comment: Hello @Marcella, welcome to UX.SE! Do your other creation functions for Manufacturing Site, Dispatch Site, and Contacts already exist within modals, or take the user to a dedicated page?

Comment: Thanks, @maxathousand!
The other creation functions for Manufacturing Site, Dispatch Site, and Contacts also are popups, but will less input fields.

Comment: I would suggest that all of those tables (manufacturing sites, dispatch sites, etc.) should be their own dedicated pages/steps in the wizard. You could then have the table at the top and then the details (i.e. form) can be the bottom half of the page